# Is it a good idea to use REST webservice to upload files?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am studying REST with JAX-RS, and this doubt just came to my mind:

Since  web services are meant to serve inter-operable clients written in different programming languages and the clients just use the URLs to access the services features; what about a web service for uploading files to a common database?

Will it be save? How can the web service avoid being overloaded by spam if he has no control over how do the clients perform validation? 
The method for upload will look more ore less similar to this:

```
@Path("/upload/{something}") 
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@POST
public void uploadSomething(...) {
//...
}
```

So my doubt is if uploading is a good thing that REST services can do safely?

Comment: @nobeh I am sorry i am not from an english speaking country i don't really understand the difference between both words.
 What i want to say is my question is will the database be safe from spam, if we have no control on the clients, we just give them the URL to upload?

Comment: I suggest using separation of concerns; the ones that I could recognize: (a) preventing malicious data from upload form or spam detection (b) constraining users to be able to upload specific files (c) as @aleroot mentioned, allowing specific user to upload using security features. Each of these I suppose have different ways to approach. Other than than, I believe using JAX-RS multipart feature would work fine.

Comment: @nobeh I understand, so i can add some validation at the webservice side to decrease the chance of spam. I will have a look around to see what decide which could be best. 
Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are concerned about safe access why you do not enforce authentication to the client ?
You can implement a **SecurityContext** and use it in your Java code to access the authentication information. Take a look at [this](http://www.butonic.de/2010/06/18/a-simple-jax-rs-security-context-example-in-glassfish/) article could be helpful.